# tail file till last duplicate line in a file using bash

Tags: bash

Hey everyone! How to in **simple** way find line number of last duplicate in file 
I need take tale till last duplicate   Example

```
hhhh
 str1
 str2
hhhh
 str1
hhh
**str1
str2
str3**
```

I need only bold till hhh(str1,str2,str3).Thanks in advance!

Comment: i have a problem understanding your problem.

Comment: "str1" is a duplicate of "str1" or "hhh" (3) is a duplicate of "hhhh" (4)? You want the "str1/str2/str3" output or the lines before?

Comment: from the end In this case it ll be    str3 str2 str1 becouse they are written after hhh and hhh is last duplicate in this file

Comment: I consider ==> hhh duplicate it will be constant so i need find last hhh in the file  and then get lines after it in some simple way .Thanks

Comment: When you say "till" do you mean "after" ("till" means "before")? Your example data has "hhh" and "hhhh" which are not duplicates and "str1" duplicated and "str2" duplicated. This is confusing. See my answer for a guess as to what you may want.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
awk '{if (a[$0]) accum = nl = ""; else {a[$0]=1;accum = accum nl $0; nl = "\n"}} END { print accum}' inputfile
```

Given this input:

```
aaa
b
c
aaa
d
e
f
aaa
b
aaa
g
h
i
```

This is the output:

```
g
h
i
```

Answer (score 0):

taking the sample from Dennis,

```
$ gawk -vRS="aaa" 'END{print}'  file

g
h
i
```

here's another way if you don't know before hand, although not as elegant as one awk script.

```
var=$(sort file| uniq -c|sort -n | tail -1| awk '{print $2}')
gawk -vRS="$var" 'END{print}'  file
```

still, this will only get the duplicate that occurs the most frequency. it does not get the "last duplicate" , whatever that means.

Comment: That works if you know what the string is beforehand and it doesn't take into account whether it's duplicated.

Comment: i see, didn't know that it would be unknown before hand

Comment: To be fair, we know little about the requirements. The pipeline wouldn't produce the correct results for "bbb\na\na\nbbb\nc\nd\n".